# Best practices: safest method to store passwords in a table?

Tags: php, security, password-encryption

I am using PHP. I used to use native mysql function password() to store passwords. I was told that password() is not safe anymore. What would be the best method to store passwords in PHP? is it MD5?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Updated Answer 2016:

The winner of the [PHC](https://password-hashing.net/) (Password Hashing Competion) was [Argon2](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2). Hashing passwords with Argon2 is the best practice as of 2016.

> PHC ran from 2013 to 2015 as an open competition—the same kind of process as NIST's AES and SHA-3 competitions, and the most effective way to develop a crypto standard. We received 24 candidates, including many excellent designs, and selected one winner, Argon2, an algorithm designed by Alex Biryukov, Daniel Dinu, and Dmitry Khovratovich from University of Luxembourg.
>
> We recommend that use you use Argon2 rather than legacy algorithms.

The [reference implementation is available on GitHub](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2).

### Updated Answer 2012:

The original answer I gave below was once considered to be a best practice. However, advances in hash-computing technology have rendered these schemes vulnerable. Going forward, the only secure password hashing schemes are iterative hashes such as [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) and [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). For a full discussion, see [Jeff Atwood's analysis](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html).

### Original Answer 2009:

I recommend first prepending a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) value to your password, followed by [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) the resultant string with a reasonably strong hashing function like [SHA256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA256). This secures against the obvious (plain text passwords) and the not so obvious (attack using [Rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)).

Keep in mind that if you store passwords in this way, you will *not* be able to retrieve a user's lost password. They'll only be able to reset passwords. This is because you'll be using  a [one way hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_hash). But this limitation is generally worth the tradeoff for a more secure password storage system. Even if your database is compromised, your user's passwords will still be exceedingly difficult and probably unpractical to recover by a would be attacker.

Comment: This is one of two ways of dealing with passwords. The other is; don't. Use OpenId/Facebook Connect/Live Auth/something else; in other words; let somebody else store the password.

Comment: is bcrypt better than this setup?

Comment: Yes, use bcrypt rather than doing this. bcrypt is doing all the good things described above for you, plus more.

Comment: @hatorade, @tialaramex: I was not familiar with bcrypt at the time I wrote this answer. I have since learned the benefits of iterative hashing. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

bcrypt is actually more secure. See: [Enough With The Rainbow Tables: What You Need To Know About Secure Password Schemes](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to salt the password.

vBulletin does a pretty good job at storing passwords.  md5(md5(password) + salt);

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of double-md5ing is... thats just a form of security through obsecurity isn't it? "oh they'll never guess that i md5'd it twice!"

Comment: A rainbow attack gets really hard to crack. It's now 32 characters plus the three salt.

Answer (score 2):

To argue with the the other answer, VBulletin does a horrid job of hashing passwords.  Their salt is only 3 characters long, only fractionally increasing the security of your application.

Check out http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ .  They do an excellent job of using a long hash, unique to each password, and running the password through md5 thousands of times.  It is one of the best hashing systems for php out there.

Comment: MD5? :( Thousands of times? Double :(

Comment: Which algorithm are you looking at? Unless they suddenly changed it, it last used 2048 passes of md5, each using the salt.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid storing the user password that's your best option, imo. Use OpenId (like Stackoverflow) to authenticate the user. Or Live Authentication (http://dev.live.com/liveid/). If you really, really need to authenticate the users yourself; do what Asaph says in his answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Salt and hash.

We typically use a random guid as the salt and then SHA512 to hash.