# Call to undefined function hash() in /var/www/site/ problem

Tags: php

I have called hash function in my code like (php version 5.2.14 )

```
$username =hash("sha256",trim($_POST['username']));
$password =hash("sha256",trim($_POST['password']));
```

but I got error like
**Call to undefined function hash() in /var/www/site/**
What to do ?

Comment: what version of PHP do you have? if you take a look at the documentation http://jp.php.net/manual/zh/function.hash.php, you would notice that you need a PHP 5 >= 5.1.2 or the pecl module .....

Comment: Do you have hash enabled in your phpinfo();

Comment: Hi there.  Which Php version are you using? Be sure hash is defined in that version...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means it cannot find the function `hash()`. Checking the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) I see this:

```
(PHP 5 >= 5.1.2, PECL hash >= 1.1)
```

What php version do you run? Try:

```
<? phpinfo() ?>
```

To check. If it is lower then 5.1.2 you do not have the `hash()` function available

Answer (score 2):

'hash()' was introduced in PHP 5.1.2, so it's possible you have an older version.

Answer (score 2):

Check your PHP version because the hash function is only available for version PHP 5 >= 5.1.2 with PECL hash >= 1.1

Answer (score 1):

If your version of PHP > 5.1.2, then enable the hash extension by uncommenting its line in the php.ini config file in use and restarting the web server

Answer (score 0):

If you do have an older version, you can still revert to the sha1 or sha256 functions as follows:

```
$username = sha1(trim($_POST['username']));
$password = sha1(trim($_POST['password']));
```

OR

```
$username = sha256(trim($_POST['username']));
$password = sha256(trim($_POST['password']));
```

HOWEVER there is a good argument about both here: [SHA1 vs md5 vs SHA256: which to use for a PHP login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235158/php-sha1-vs-md5-vs-sha256-which-to-use-for-a-php-login)