# PHP 5.3.20: undefined function hash()

Tags: php, hash

I'm trying to install Magento on FreeBSD with PHP 5.3.20, but the install script fails with

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function hash() in /var/www/.../magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 894`

As it's cleared in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591975/call-to-undefined-function-hash-in-var-www-site-problem) it requires PHP 5.1.2, so that's a different problem. I installed the `php5-mhash` extension from ports and added mhash.so and hash.so to the extensions.ini. Also, there is no `--disable-hash` in the configure command. And it's the same in CLI too.

Probably because open_basedir? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing it from security and see if this will work for you.

```
cd /usr/ports/security/php5-hash 
make install clean
```