# PHP hash() error function

Tags: php

Each time I try to use the `hash()` function, it gives me a fatal error for undefined function `hash()`.

First thing I do is check `phpinfo()` and see if hash is actually present.  `Phpinfo()` does tell me `hash()` is available.  Doesn't mean it's loaded, so when I check my `ini file`, the `pgsql PDO` is commented out yet the `PDO` is working just fine (I guess the generic PDO is always loaded by default).  There is also no entry for hash and I wouldn't know the extension name anyways.  But, it should have been installed.

Using `PHP 7.0.1` on `Mac OS X.11` and I used this website http://php-osx.liip.ch as `phpbrew` just doesn't want to work right for me.

- UPDATE -

I decided to go look inside the directory structure where php is installed and noticed that other extensions have their own INI files in the php.d directory.  How does one know if the hash extension requires it's own INI file?  Or is this just an easier way to enable extensions without having to tinker with INI production and development configurations?

Comment: I don't know if this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17384252/5442132

Comment: Using `find` I cannot find any appropriately named `so` file.  Either hash.so is bundled into something else, or it wasn't installed with `php` as `phpinfo` says it was.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  While my page dumps out `phpinfo()` saying version `7.0.2` with all the needed extensions, my `CLI` version is still liked to `5.6.16` and missing extensions.

As they say, an assumption is the mother of any screw-up.  I assumed the installer for `7.0.2` would rename the Apple provided one and/or link to the newer binary.