# Encryption sha512 algorithm Different values

Tags: php, hash, authentication, cryptography, sha512

So I have been using this login and register script for about 3 projects and it worked great. But for the current project its creating certain problems. The generated password doesnt match with the one in the DB and hence couldnt login.

The register page is given below

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Registration Form</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        if (!empty($error_msg)) {
            echo $error_msg;
        }
        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" 
                method="post" 
                name="registration_form">
            Username: <input type='text' 
                name='username' 
                id='username' /><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
            Password: <input type="password"
                             name="password" 
                             id="password"/><br>
            Confirm password: <input type="password" 
                                     name="confirmpwd" 
                                     id="confirmpwd" /><br>
            <input type="button" 
                   value="Register" 
                   onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password,
                                   this.form.confirmpwd);" /> 
        </form>
        <p>Return to the <a href="index.php">login page</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

register.inc.php Page given below

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT license_num FROM doctor_details WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
        }
                $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
                $stmt->close();
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT license_num FROM doctor_details WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                        // A user with this username already exists
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
                $stmt->close();
        } else {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error line 55</p>';
                $stmt->close();
        }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE)); // Did not work
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO doctor_details (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    }
}
?>
```

The registering work fine.. and the data gets entered onto DB. for illustration i have created a test record with 
email = test@testing.com
password = Pass123

Password and Salt as entered in DB
Password : `1ca2a523757d457a4df261c647dc45349ca8c721f76fa2b54e`

Salt :`ae2788757a98b0750d0aaecb9735cc27d92d29413cab1c89fb741cf735fd551322f94993b7cb79cd4ade2dea221142dcac7aa380b776db7fa05bf6c6b5d32056`

The hashed password when i try to login is

```
d01feaafb5359e1fa2c020a76ebb526fc75786b0b837e0c9a4dcabd58ad734efa469513cf66a272d5ef4b1b9646b4b39f50807afc8f8663e1c6bb23552b04cd6
```

Login Page

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../login.php?error=1');
    }
}
```

Login Function given below

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT license_num, username, password, salt 
        FROM doctor_details
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The DB structure is

license_num ( Primary)
email
password
username
salt

Is it because license_num is not Auto Increment?

Thanks if you could help out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2235189/2224584 - Please don't use SHA512 for password hashes. Also, [don't compare with `==`](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2015/05/phps-magic-hash-vulnerability-or-beware-of-type-juggling/)