# PHP equivalent passwords hashing of the following .NET code

Tags: php, cryptography, passwords, sha512, pbkdf2

I don't really want to dump some code and expect answers but this is a pretty lengthy function that hashes a password in order to later compare it to the database-stored value.

I have seen posts where people wasted time trying to recreate what they could achieve with the `md5()` function in PHP.

For that reason, I'm wondering if someone with any encryption knowledge knows of a PHP equivalent to achieve the following effect in PHP:

```
    internal static string GenerateEncryptedPassword(string password, string salt, int iterationCount)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
        byte[] iterationCountBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(iterationCount);
        int derivedLength = passwordBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length;
        byte[] passwordSaltBytes = new byte[derivedLength];
        byte[] pbkdf2Bytes;
        string encryptedString;

        for (int i = 0; i < passwordBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            passwordSaltBytes[i] = passwordBytes[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            passwordSaltBytes[passwordBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];
        }

        using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, passwordSaltBytes, iterationCount))
        {
            pbkdf2Bytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(derivedLength + iterationCountBytes.Length);
        }

        using (SHA512 sha512 = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = sha512.ComputeHash(pbkdf2Bytes);
            byte[] hashSaltBytes = new byte[hashBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                hashSaltBytes[i] = hashBytes[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                hashSaltBytes[hashBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];
            }

            encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashSaltBytes);
        }

        return encryptedString;
    }
```

If it changes anything, I'm using Laravel...

Thank you for any guidance

---

I hate encryption :D

```
$user = \App\User::all();
$salt = strtolower($user[2]->Salt);
$password = 'P@$$W0rd';
$dbPassword = $user[2]->Password;
$iterations = 10000;

echo openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, 44, $iterations, 'sha512');
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the PHP manual for password_hash and password_verify. I recommend using BCrypt as the algorithm.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

It's not difficult at all! Good luck! :-)

Also, SHA-512 isn't all that secure. Read here: [SHA1 vs md5 vs SHA256: which to use for a PHP login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235158/sha1-vs-md5-vs-sha256-which-to-use-for-a-php-login/2235189#2235189)

Comment: Thing is, I have to recreate what my co-worker has already done, and so I cannot use anything else. It must output the same hash. I certainly tried a couple of things before posting here, but I'll take a look again, thank you.

Comment: You can try password_hash() using SHA512 too, check the options for it!

Comment: Again, I've looked at the options and I've obviously ran a good dozen combinations and overloads, that's why I resorted to pasting that code in here in hopes that someone perhaps knows a way to do it conveniently quickly in PHP..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PHP for years so not sure if there are new ways to do things, but you can produce SHA-512 hashes with OpenSSL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-digest.php

```
openssl_digest(pbkdf2Bytes, 'sha512');
```

To generate salt, it is highly recommended to use secure (unpredictable) randoms. For PHP, see this: [PHP random string generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator/31107425#31107425)

**EDIT:**
You can also produce pbkfd2 directly with OpenSSL:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pbkdf2.php

Just note the optional parameter in the end of the function signature where you define the digest algorithm.

```
openssl_pbkdf2(password, saltBytes, keyLength, iterationCount, 'sha512')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does this support salts?

Comment: I made an edit to answer to your question :) Generally speaking you can hash any data you want. In your code snippet you have concatenated salt + password, which is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. :)

Comment: No problem. Hope you get it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks - my head is still exploding over this lol. Can't figure anything out, completely blocked.

Comment: That implementation seems to be giving me random characters 
'�Έ�����#�̀P6���H]Љ6S �lr ����Y�`�'
o.O - if I base64_encode it, it looks fine, but it doesn't match the correct hash

Comment: Could you add your php code as an update to the original post?

Comment: done, it's the same line you posted with some prior db querying.