# Function in Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, normalize

Does anyone know how to convert this function from Python to PHP?

I have been around it but there is things in Python code I can't figure out.

This function is used in the follow context:
http://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/general.html#authentication

```
def normalize(input=None):
output = ''

if type(input) in (list, tuple):
    for element in input:
        if type(element) in (dict, list, tuple):
            element = normalize(element)
        output += str(element)

elif type(input) is dict:
    keys = input.keys()
    keys.sort()
    for key in keys:
        element = input[key]
        if type(element) in (dict, list, tuple):
            element = normalize(element)
        output += '%s%s' % (key, element)

else:
    output = str(input)

return output
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this function is used, and how you plan to use it in PHP?  It uses language specific python features which don't directly translate.

Comment: It does converts json content in recursive text without any spaces, etc. Please take a look here to the example: http://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/general.html#authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php has no distinction between dictionaries and tuples/lists, so:

```
function normalize($input=null) {
  if (! is_array($input)) {
    return strval($input);
  }

  $res = '';
  $keys = array_keys($input);
  sort($keys);
  foreach ($keys as $k) {
    if (!is_int($k)) $res .= $k;
    $res .= normalize($v);
  }
  return $res;
}
```

Notably, this serialization sucks, since it cannot distinguish integers from numbers. YOu should really be using JSON (in [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as well as [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps)), which is a language-independent, human-readable serialization format.

Instead of using this string for authentication, one should simply use a [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068058/good-cryptographic-hash-functions) over the JSON serialization.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the link on the original post. The objective is break the JSON readable format for authentication purposes.

Comment: @PGZ I've seen that, and added a paragraph about how that's a bad idea as well. Does this php code work for you?

Comment: @PGZ Sorry, I don't understand. What precisely do you mean by JSON code? The JSON serialization? The input structure? Note that neither one is changed by the Python code as well.

Comment: If I place on a JSON code like "call": "media.get_assets", "args": {"a":"b"}, it does not affects it.