# Which one is better? using your own encrypting algorithm or using md5/sha1?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

[image]

I want my passwords to be secure in database. Even if someone leaks the passwords I don't want anyone to be able to decrypt them.

Comment: Don't use md5. Just use PHP's `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: use sha256 or sha512 with salt to hash passwords.

Comment: md5 / sha1 are hashing algorithms, not encryption. If you're asking about whether to do your own encryption on SO, the answer is no.

Comment: Follow this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624372/best-practice-for-hashing-passwords-sha256-or-sha512

Comment: No, don't follow that link. Just use the PHP [password API](http://php.net/password) as @MrDarkLynx suggests.

Comment: For passwords you don't use encryption, you use secure hashing and **DO NOT** use something you made yourself. Existing algorithms have gone through rigorous testing and evaluation and many of them are fit for purpose, you can't offer such guarantees in anything you devise yourself. `password_hash` and `password_verify` is the suggested approach in PHP.

Comment: Which is better? Learning the difference between encryption and hashing to start with.... without knowing that, writing your own encryption certainly isn't going to be secure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Answer (score 3):

Passwords are hashed, not encrypted. There is a big difference. You must understand that encrypted strings can be retrieved by decrypting them. This is not possible when hashing. Hashes are, most of the time, not reversible and passwords are checked by matching the hashes. Hash methods such as MD5 have been cracked and are therefore not safe anymore as the password can be "unhashed".

You should not attempt to make your own hashing algorithm as it will most likely have major security flaws. Current day algorithms have been developed by countless of security and cryptography experts and have been analyzed over and over again. There is just a zero percent chance that your backyard algorithm will be more secure than algorithms developed by experts.

Just use the PHP default methods which are `password_hash` and `password_verify`.
The hashing function generates a random salt by itself which is appended to the hashed password. It is therefore a very safe method and your best bet.

Comment: Added the paragraph, thanks for the suggestion.